# How does for loop work in a PL/pgSQL stored procedure?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, database-cursor

As per PostgreSQL documentation on [cursors](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-cursors.html), for loops use `cursors` internally.

> However, PL/pgSQL users do not normally need to worry about that, since FOR loops automatically use a cursor internally to avoid memory problems.

So according to this, using for loops should be a good option to stream data to the client. But then, Postgres [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html) also states the following about RETURN NEXT (which is generally used inside for loop).

> The current implementation of RETURN NEXT and RETURN QUERY stores the entire result set before returning from the function, as discussed above. That means that if a PL/pgSQL function produces a very large result set, performance might be poor: data will be written to disk to avoid memory exhaustion, but the function itself will not return until the entire result set has been generated.

My confusion is if Postgres eventually waits for the entire result set to be fetched from the server then what's the purpose of having a cursor in the for loop?

Comment: Well, a cursor is not only used to return data. It's also used to simply iterate over a set of rows.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. But don't you think it's a little peculiar that if a cursor is being used to speed up the query execution then why 'return next' does not take advantage of this streaming. Why does it wait for all the results to pile up?

Comment: RETURN NEXT/QUERY are used with setof  which means they are returning an entire set as it stands now. As the docs say that may change in future. If you want to stream data then return a cursor.

Comment: A cursor isn't used to "speed up the query execution".